# How to install MySQLdb in Python 2.6 CentOS

Tags: python, centos, mysql-python

I am getting this message when I use `yum install mysql-python` to install MySQLdb.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
 * extras: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
 * updates: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
base                                                      | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                    | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package mysql-python available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**Update**
Result for `yum repolist`

```
root@server [~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
 * extras: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
 * updates: mirrors.sin3.sg.voxel.net
base                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00
repo id              repo name                        status
base                 CentOS-6 - Base                  6,019+362
extras               CentOS-6 - Extras                13
updates              CentOS-6 - Updates               802+140
repolist: 6,834
```

Comment: Try using `pip`. `pip install mysqldb-python`.

Comment: `pip install` or `easy_install`??

Comment: MySQL-python is in the base repo. `yum install MySQL-python`

Comment: I used easy_install
`root@server [~]# easy_install mysqldb-python`
`Searching for mysqldb-python`
`Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqldb-python/`
`Couldn't find index page for 'mysqldb-python' (maybe misspelled?)`
`Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)`
`Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/`
`No local packages or download links found for mysqldb-python`
`error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('mysqldb-python')`

Answer (score 15):

You can install it via `yum`, it is case sensitive:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install MySQL-python
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.nfsi.pt
 * extras: mirrors.nfsi.pt
 * updates: mirrors.nfsi.pt
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MySQL-python.x86_64 0:1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
...
```

It works with the following repositories (CentOS 6):

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.nfsi.pt
 * extras: mirrors.nfsi.pt
 * updates: mirrors.nfsi.pt
repo id      repo name            status
base         CentOS-6 - Base      6.381
extras       CentOS-6 - Extras    12
updates      CentOS-6 - Updates   458
repolist: 6.851
```

Comment: Still got this message
`Setting up Install Process`
`No package MySQL-python available.`
`Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: Yeah, here's the result
`Setting up Update Process`
`No Packages marked for Update`

Comment: Check your repositories and your network configuration, it should work perfectly on CentOS 6.x

Comment: Unless you have any problem with your network, firewall or whatever, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to install it using `yum`, your configuration seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

`MySQL-python` exists in [`PyPi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4). Try doing either of the following :

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

or

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for all the help but none of them works for me. I found this [interesting article](http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/) on web on how to set up the package for Python 2.6 CentOS 5.5, this works for me.

First, I install some stuffs used to build RPMs

```
yum -y install rpm-build gcc-c++
```

And some dependencies

```
yum -y install readline-devel openssl-devel gmp-devel ncurses-devel
yum -y install gdbm-devel expat-devel libGL-devel libX11-devel tcl-devel tk-devel
yum -y install tix-devel sqlite-devel db4-devel
```

Grabbed src RPM

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirrors.geekymedia.com/centos/python26-2.6-geekymedia1.src.rpm
```

And lastly

```
yum install -y mysql-devel
curl http://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mysql-python/mysql-python/1.2.3/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz | tar zxv
cd MySQL-python-1.2.3
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the EPEL Repo:

```
/bin/rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm creates=/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

then enable it in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`: set `enabled=1`

try `yum install gcc-c++ MySQL-python` afterwards.