# Installing mysqldb with a new version of python on linux

Tags: python, linux, mysql-python

I have mysqldb installed and it works for python2.4.  But I've recently installed python2.6 and when I run it I can't import mysqldb.  I get the following:

```
import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I've looked over how to install mysqldb (it's been a few years since I installed it), but can't find anything on how to reinstall or make it work with a new version of python.  Any thoughts?

I made some progress by adding a path to my .bashrc file (the first one, whic is where my MySQLdb installation is for python2.4):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages:/usr/lib/python2.4:/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

so now when I run python2.6 and try import MySQLdb I get

import MySQLdb

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 27, in 
    import _mysql

ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4

I don't know what to do about this.  Maybe install MySQLdb again with python2.6?  (I've actually tried this and it's hard to install MySQLdb with or without setuptools.  I did it once more than a year ago but forgot what I did.  My server behind a firewall, so setuptools doesn't work out of the box.)  Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620483/how-to-install-mysqldb-in-python-2-6-centos

Comment: install python-pymssql library

Comment: @Ank: I checked out that question and it's very different from what I'm asking.

Comment: @drabo2005: That library looks like it's for Windows.  I'm talking Linux.

Comment: i don't know windows, only Ubuntu (linux)

Answer (score 0):

Which python version is on your path? You can determine this by typing

```
which python
```

It should return the location with py26 if it's referencing version 2.6

Then, try

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

This should install the correct version for 2.6

You can also download python-mysqldb directly [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

Comment: I have multiple versions installed, 2.4 and 2.6.  Currently it's 2.4 that's in my path.  To run python2.6 I type python 2.6.  What do I do to install mysqldb for python2.6?  Should I try sudo apt-get install python2.6-mysqldb?

Comment: ... Or if I install directly from the tarball, how do I reference python2.6?  As I said, I already have mysqldb installed for python (python2.4).