# How to Install MySQLdb in PyCharm, Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, mysql-python

I am new to Python(I am using Python2.6) and Pycharm, but I need to use `MySQLdb` module to complete my task.

I found [How to install MySQLdb in Python 2.6 CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620483/how-to-install-mysqldb-in-python-2-6-centos) but I need it at Windows 7(64 bits)

Is there any way to easily install this module using Pycharm? I am using Pycharm(3.1.1 professional)

I spent time to search for some guides or tips and finally I go to here but does not found `MySQLdb` to install.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On windows:

The best way is to download it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

then run the executable. It will look for your Python 2.7 path from Windows path and install this package/module. This will resolve your issue in Pycharm because Pycharm also looks into Window path for this package.

In Pycharm open file try import MySQLdb it will show available. or do command import MySQLdb in Pycharm terminal window, if you do not see ImportError then it is ready.

Linux user go here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

Comment: This finally works! With some tweaks you can even use it on a virtualenv copying MySQLdb files inside the environment. I've added some screenshot here: https://chirale.org/2017/03/01/python-mysqldb-on-windows-virtualenv-w-figures/